# how to split resource in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

In Jersey we can do something like

```
@Path("/")
public class TopResource{
 
    @GET
    public Response getTop() { ... }
 
    @Path("content")
    public ContentResource getContentResource() {
        return new ContentResource();
    }

}
 
public class ContentResource {
 
    @GET
    public Response getContent() { ... }
}
```

so,

`https://<host>` will invoke `getTop()`

`https://<host>/content` will invoke `getContent()`

is there any equivalent in Spring?

I tried

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TopResource{
 
    @GetMapping()
    public Response getTop() { ... }
 
    @RequestMapping("content")
    public ContentResource getContentResource() {
        return new ContentResource();
    }

}

@RestController
public class ContentResource {
 
    @GetMapping()
    public Response getContent() { ... }
}
```

only top resource works. `content` would return 404 Not Found.
Not sure how to do this in Spring Boot.
Tried replacing `@RestController` with `@Resource` and `@Controller` for content, but still got 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to retun a whole class, please use the Annotation @RequestMapping on top of your content class to split them up.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TopResource{
 
    @GetMapping()
    public Response getTop() { ... }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("content")
public class ContentResource {
 
    @GetMapping()
    public Response getContent() { ... }
}
```